# How to use last() inside xsl:matching-substring?

Tags: xml, regex, xpath, xslt-2.0

Is there a way to determine if a `xsl:matching-substring` is the `last()` matching substring?

Example data:

```
<data>
    <value>1 A 1 2 B 2 1 C 3</value>
</data>
```

Example XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output media-type="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title>xsl:matching-substring problem</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>xsl:matching-substring problem</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//value">
        <xsl:element name="p" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\p{{Nd}}\s\p{{Lu}}\s\p{{Nd}}" flags="i">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:if test="not(last())">
                        <xsl:element name="br" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
                    </xsl:if />
                </xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>xsl:matching-substring problem</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>xsl:matching-substring problem</h1>
      <p>1 A 12 B 21 C 3</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

So, it seems `last()` is true also for the first and the second matching substring (in fact, `last()` seems to return the position of the last character of the matching substring).

Without the `xsl:if`, i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>xsl:matching-substring problem</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>xsl:matching-substring problem</h1>
      <p>1 A 1<br />2 B 2<br />1 C 3<br /></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

But i would prefer `<p>1 A 1<br />2 B 2<br />1 C 3</p>`. Is there a way to achieve this using XSLT 2.0? (Im using Saxon HE as xslt engine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Joel_M.Lamsen has identified a bug in your code, but his solution isn't correct.

The spec says this: In processing each substring, the contents of the substring will be the context item (as a value of type xs:string); the position of the substring within the sequence of matching and non-matching substrings will be the context position; and the number of matching and non-matching substrings will be the context size.

So (position()=last()) tests whether you are processing the last substring, which may be either a matching or a non-matching substring. If you are in xsl:matching-substring, processing the last matching substring, then (position()=last()) will return false if there is a non-matching substring still to come.

Since you are not interested in the non-matching substrings, a better solution is to use tokenize():

```
<xsl:template match="value">
    <xhtml:p>
       <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\p{{Nd}}\s\p{{Lu}}\s\p{{Nd}}', 'i')">
          <xsl:if test="position() ne 1"><xhtml:br/></xsl:if> 
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </xhtml:p>
</xsl:template>
```

Note also some other stylistic improvements I have made to your code:

- The pattern //value should almost certainly be just "value"
- Replacing xsl:element by literal result elements
- Instead of inserting a separator after every item except the last, insert it before every item except the first. Testing whether an item is the last involves look-ahead, which can be inefficient; testing whether it is the first is much simpler.

I would also be inclined to avoid the 'i' flag in the regex; instead replace `\p{Lu}` by some larger category.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
```

instead